# unable to create application pool in wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, application-pool

I am creating wix installation and I am trying to create application pool and add it to the application. The problem is that application pool is not created during installation. When I create application pool with same parameters manually and run installation after that, pool is correctly associated with the application. I run installation with log enabled and only thing, I can find about app pool is this line:

> MSI (s) (A0:D4) [13:21:31:109]: Component: AppPool; Installed: Null;   Request: Local;   Action: Local

So, obviously my app pool is not created, but I can't figure it why, and how to fix it. My wix code is like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="AppPool" Guid="75BFA004-8C69-4102-B26B-BBC54F3F9448" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="myAppPoolId"
            Name="myAppPool"               
      Identity="applicationPoolIdentity"
      ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated"
      ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
    </Component>
  <Component Id="InstallWebsite" Guid="1D51BC31-7F7E-4D63-8A6C-3213090F629A" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VirtualDir" 
                       Alias="myApp" 
                       Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
                       WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="VirtualDirProperties"
          AnonymousAccess="no"
          BasicAuthentication="no"
          WindowsAuthentication="yes"
          DefaultDocuments="index.html" />
      <iis:WebApplication Id="myAppId"
                Name="myApp"
                WebAppPool="myAppPoolId"/>          
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>        
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Every things seems fine in "AppPool" component.
Add install website component like :

```
<iis:WebSite ConfigureIfExists="yes" Id="webId" Description='DESCRIPTION' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' AutoStart='yes' StartOnInstall='yes'  >
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="1122" />
      <iis:WebApplication Id="MailboxMigrationAppPool" Name="[NAME]" WebAppPool="myAppPoolId"></iis:WebApplication>
</iis:WebSite>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions...I allready have website, just outside of components...nevertheless I have tried your suggestion, but it didn't help...